# Throwable: No emulator binary found! when starting AVD in Android Studio 1.1.0 on Mac OS

Tags: android, ide, android-virtual-device

I am working on an Android app with Android Studio on Mac OS. It worked fine, but now, I get the error in the Android console " Throwable: No emulator binary found" when starting the AVD in Android Studio. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable and then Enable ADB Integration

In Android Studio go to

```
Menu -> Tools
Android
Enable ADB Integration (uncheck box)
Enable ADB Integration (check box)
```

Comment: That was very helpful! Great, thanks a lot for the quick reply.